# Multiple JOIN with FETCH in Criteria API

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have a JPQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT b 
    FROM
        Book b 
    INNER JOIN
        FETCH b.volumes as v 
    INNER JOIN
        v.metadata as md 
    WHERE
        b.createdAt IN (
            SELECT
                MAX(book.createdAt) 
            FROM
                Book book 
            WHERE
                book.author = ?1 
        ) 
        AND md.genre IN (
            ?2
        )
```

Since this has to be generated dynamically, I need to use Criteria API to add various conditions. I can get everything right except for the JOINs, because the first one is a fetch and I'm not able to chain that one with the next.

This is what I have so far:

```java
    query.distinct(true);
    final Join<Book, Metadata> Metadata = root.join("volumes").join("metadata");

    final Subquery<LocalDateTime> subquery = query.subquery(LocalDateTime.class);
    final Root<Book> plan = subquery.from(Book.class);
    subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(plan.get("author"), companyId));
    final Expression<LocalDateTime> createdAt = book.get("createdAt");
    subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.greatest(createdAt));

    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get("createdAt")).value(subquery));

    genre.ifPresent(strings -> predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.in(metadata.get("genre")).value(strings)));

    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Any idea on how to make the first join a fetch?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for it in the Root class. Without second parameter it is inner join fetch

`root.fetch("volumes")`